# Adb server failed to ack, daemon not running. android sdk

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-emulator, adk

i have been trying to fix this problem but no luck. I have tried almost all way but no luck.
When i kill adb and when i start it, it says it started successfully but after that again it says it cannot connect. Any good answer would be so helpful. This is so frustating....

Answer (score 0):

You will need to kill `adb` via task Manager then go to `.android` folder, delete the cache and delete `ddms.cfg`, then restart Eclipse. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

killing adb via task manager / activity monitor (windows) then adb start-server worked for me.

I also changed genymotions to use the android SDK instead of genymotions custom SDK.  Genymotion -> Settings -> ADB -> Path to your Android SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but mine didn't work because of Avast. After removing avast, it worked.